# What does the list multiply by one do in a list comprehension below?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Hi I have read some topics in [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135482/72735) and I am having difficulties in understanding the last part of the list comprehension:

`lambda l:[i+l.pop()for i in l*1]`

why we multiply the list by 1? If I remove the `*1` I get one item less in the list.

Comment: The reason for `l*1` is explained in the comments of the post you linked.

Comment: In fact, it was explained in the comments *in direct response to you asking about it*, 15 hours ago.

Comment: A more verbose form would be: `[x + l[-i] for i, x in enumerate(l, 1)]`

Comment: @randomir, I know, because I asked, check the line above "dhssa" is the one who asked yesterday, I have asked here because  wanted more elaborated answer like one below.

Comment: @user2357112, does that mean I am forbidden to ask it here? I don't think would hurt the quality of SOF, I was in search of more elaborated answer and I believe this will benefit some one like me who comes here, but not Code Golf, I feel hostility here, scary hostility.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I don't think my question violates the T.C of S.O.F, I can ask questions which is related to coding in python and the point in the question is rare, not explained in many text books, I thought some one who is like me new to python can learn something new as well. I have acknowledged the comment in Code Golf, so I don't need reminders that I have asked. Please compare the comment in Code Golf and the answer below and think about how many new python programmer will benefit from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying by one gives you a shallow copy of the list, which will be unaffected by the `list.pop` operations you're performing afterwards, making the behaviour of the comprehension *consistent* and *umambiguous*; since you're not popping from the same list over which you're iterating.

They could easily create a shallow copy with the more intuitive `l[:]` or the more verbose `copy.copy(l)`, but that would take more characters, and the goal of code golf is to use as few characters as possible.

Comment: Why not use the more common `l[:]`?

Comment: @CoryMadden Because the code was taken from **code golf**?

Comment: @CoryMadden it's an example of *code golf*. `l[:]` is one more character than `l*1`

Comment: Ah, thanks. I haven't heard the term Code Golf in a while and didn't make the connection.